# Como criar uma trigger que seja disparada sempre que tiver um evento de inserção na tabela?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Preciso criar uma *trigger* que seja disparada sempre que tiver um evento de inserção na tabela, antes de ser efetuado a inserção, ela verifique uma condição, se a condição for respeitada ela altera o valor de um certo campo que esta sendo inserido.

Exemplo:

```
-- id do registro atual que esta sendo inserido 
if id_pai = 0 or null
 -- ela pega este ID, faz um select em outra tabela ( select id from tabela2 where id_nota = id_nota.
 -- pega o resultado que seria o ID do registro da tabela2 e insere no campo 
 -- id_pai do registro que esta sendo inserido.
end;
```

Andei pesquisando alguns modelos como construir a trigger, porém, não sei como trabalhar na questão dela manipular o campo que esta sendo inserido, e alterar o valor.

Comment: Você deve utilizar uma trigger `INSTEAD OF`, e nela tu manipula os dados selecionando os dados enviados as tabelas `inserted` e `deleted`, sendo que em um update a tabela `inserted` terá os novos dados e a tabela `deleted` terá os antigos dados dos registros.

Comment: Coloquei a resposta abaixo para sua pergunta, funcionando 100% porém recomendaria fazer isso via stored procedure e executada por um software externo, pois trigger consome bastante recursos.

Comment: A tua resposta vai estourar se for adicionada mais de uma linha no mesmo insert, postei a minha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@edit

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table_A_Update ON itensNota FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @IDPAI VARCHAR(200), @IDNOTA VARCHAR(200), @ID INT
BEGIN
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT idPai, idNota, ID
    FROM inserted
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @IDPAI, @IDNOTA, @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        IF ( @idPai = 0 )
                        UPDATE itensNota
                        SET idPai = ( SELECT id FROM nota WHERE idNota = @IDNOTA )
                        FROM itensNota a
                        where a.id = @ID and a.idNota = @IDNOTA
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @IDPAI, @IDNOTA, @ID
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
END
```

Comment: Me desculpa, mas sei bem pouco de de trigger, eu criei uma aqui que faz o que eu preciso: http://pastebin.com/ZTJMzYS4

Trabalha exatamente da forma que eu preciso, porém, sobre a questão de estourar, poderia me explicar melhor, @Marciano.Andrade? Ou como ficaria este código adaptado ao seu?

Comment: Por exemplo, se você usar um insert desta forma: `INSERT INTO table(Col1, Col2) Values ('1','2'), ('2', '3')` a tabela inserted vai ter dois registros, pois no insert foram passadas dois registros. Outro exemplo seria executar um insert apartir de um Select que retorne mais de um registro. Sendo assim, o seguinte trecho da tua trigger vai causar um erro: `SELECT @IDPAI = i.idPai FROM inserted i;` pois a consulta na tabela pai inserted retorna mais de um registro. Vou editar a minha resposta para que a mesma possa se adequar a tua trigger.

Comment: Continuação: Me corrigindo: O trecho `SELECT @IDPAI = i.idPai FROM inserted i;` não vai estourar, mas sim vai pegar o ultimo `idPai` que vier no inserted, fazendo com que alguns registros não sejam processados pela tua trigger. Da uma olhada nesse pastebin: http://pastebin.com/vsU1f89s

Comment: Entendi amigo, então, como ficaria o código adaptado a minha trigger?

Comment: Tem como me passar a estrutura da tabela? ai vou modificar corretamente...

Comment: Aqui esta explicação básica: http://pastebin.com/AmHBFhBY Eu montei essa estrutura básica.

Comment: @juniorb2ss Adicionei a trigger modificada, ela usa um cursor para interagir entre cada linha da inserted.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, acredito que assim tenha ficado mais profissional a trigger. Aparentemente esta funcionando corretamente, depois irei alterar para a tabela verdadeira, e testar em produção. Agradeço pela força, qualquer coisa volto a responder aqui!!!

Comment: @juniorb2ss fiz mais uma modificação, pois estava fazendo um join naquele teu update e fiquei meio cabrero em relação a ele rsrs. pode testar denovo?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER
    tg_NomeDaTriger
ON
NomedaTabela
AFTER INSERT

AS
DECLARE @ID_PAI int
SELECT top 1 @ID=ID_PAI From NomedaTabela order by CAmpoID desc
if(@ID_PAI=0)
BEGIN
  --sua logica aqui para ser executa
END
```

Exemplo funcionando perfeitamente com o banco de dados NortWind. Se inserir na tabela Categories no campo CategoryName o texto 'teste' também será inserido 'Leonardo':

```
CREATE TRIGGER
tg_NomeDaTriger
ON
dbo.Categories
AFTER INSERT

AS
DECLARE @ID_PAI varchar(200)
SELECT top 1 @ID_PAI=CategoryName from dbo.Categories order by CategoryID desc
if(@ID_PAI='teste')
BEGIN
INSERT dbo.Categories (CategoryName,Description) values ('Leonardp','')
END
```

Lembrando que apesar de TRIGGERS SQL serem muito úteis, não é aconselhável a utilização deste tipo de instrução, pelo fato de prejudicar a performance.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!